# Rails 3 Search Action Redirects To Show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, get, url-routing

I've ran into a weird problem in Rails. When I try and submit a search query with the following form on my **Uploads** controller:

```
<%= form_tag ({:controller => "uploads", :action => 'find_uploads'}), :method => "get" do %>
        <%=h text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
        <br />
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :style=>"display:inline;" %>
<% end %>
```

I get redirected to the following url and error page:

```
/uploads/find_uploads?utf8=✓&search=bot&commit=Search
```

> **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UploadsController#show**
>
> Couldn't find Upload with id=0

**My find_uploads route:** `get 'uploads/find_uploads' => "uploads#find_uploads"`

And when I did I rake routes this is what I got:

```
uploads_find_uploads GET    /uploads/find_uploads(.:format)    {:controller=>"uploads", :action=>"find_uploads"}
```

Everything seems to be in order... not sure why it's not working out as expected. For debugging purposes I dropped breakpoints in both my find_uploads and show actions and neither of them were reached so this error message must be lying to me as the UploadsController show action is never called!

This form is being rendered on my index page if it counts for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's taking `find_uploads` for an id.

Declare your routes like that:

```
resources :uploads do
    collection do
        get :find_uploads
    end
end
```

ps: currently, when you do `rake routes`, `/uploads/find_uploads` is after `/uploads/:id` right?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response Robin, and good catch that solved the problem. And yes it was after the `/uploads/:id`